# How do Vulcans handle pon farr in marriage?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

We know that Vulcans are non emotional most of the time and consider any expression of passion unacceptable. Except from when they experience pon farr every seven years - which apparently the way for them to procreate. We also know pon farr is going same way for males and females (reference T'Pol).

Once they are married how do they synchronize? It seems like a very slim chance for both of partners to come to pon farr at the same period of time.

Do one of the spouse violates the other's good will? Do they make children without waiting for any pon farr state (should be rather technical unemotional act in this case)? Do they somehow synchronize their cycles and then have a chance to procreate only once every seven years?

Comment: It would seem resonable to assume that a vulcan can have intercourse (without revulsion) without going through pon farr, and would understand the logic in doing so (so their spouse doesn't, you know, die)

Comment: a little wine... a little dinner...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> One way to interpret pon farr is that Vulcans only have sex once every seven years. However, TOS writer and continuity story editor D.C. Fontana once explained that pon farr is not the only time Vulcans feel romantic attraction, sexual desire, or engage in sexual activity:
>   "Vulcans mate normally any time they want to. However, every seven years you do the ritual, the ceremony, the whole thing. The biological urge. You must, but any other time is any other emotion – humanoid emotion – when you're in love. When you want to, you know when the urge is there, you do it. This every-seven-years business was taken too literally by too many people who don't stop and understand. We didn't mean it only every seven years. I mean, every seven years would be a little bad, and it would not explain the Vulcans of many different ages which are not seven years apart." – D.C. Fontana (Captains' Logs: The Unauthorized Complete Trek Voyages)
>
> <sub>[Memory Alpha, Pon farr](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pon_farr)</sub>

> A common misconception associated with the series (and Spock in particular) is that Vulcans only have sex once every seven years. However, pon farr is not coincident with the sex lives of Vulcans, and they are able to have intercourse without the affliction, and thus more than once every seven years. Star Trek: The Original Series writer and continuity story editor D. C. Fontana explains that pon farr is not the only time that Vulcans feel sexual desire or engage in sexual activity:
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, Pon Farr, In *Star Trek* canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pon_farr#In_Star_Trek_canon)</sub>

Vulcans can have sex during other times aside from *Pon farr*.

Comment: When using links as sources it’s best to explain why the link contents answer the question in your own words rather than relying 100% on the quote, see [the help centre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).